# Cursor loops; How to perform something at start/end of loop 1 time only?

Tags: sql, plsql, loops, oracle10g, cursor

I've got the following in one of my Oracle procedures, I'm using it to generate XML

```
  -- v_client_addons is set to '' to avoid null error
  OPEN C_CLIENT_ADDONS;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_CLIENT_ADDONS INTO CLIENT_ADDONS;
    EXIT WHEN C_CLIENT_ADDONS%NOTFOUND;
    BEGIN
      v_client_addons := v_client_addons || CLIENT_ADDONS.XML_DATA;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C_CLIENT_ADDONS;

  -- Do something later with v_client_addons
```

The loop should go through my cursor and pick out all of the XML values to display, such as :

```
<add-on name="some addon"/>
<add-on name="another addon"/>
```

What I would like to achieve is to have an XML start/end tag inside this loop, so I would have the following output

```
<addons>
   <add-on name="some addon"/>
   <add-on name="another addon"/>
</addons>
```

How can I do this without having the `<addons>` tag after every line? If there are no addons in the cursor (cursor is empty), then I would like to skip this part enitrely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the length of v_client_addons. If it is greater than 0, you actually appened something. Then create you parent tag with its children, else just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

How about using SQL to generate the entire XML, instead of looping over a cursor?

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("addons", XMLAGG(C.XML_DATA)) INTO v_client_addons 
FROM CLIENT_ADDON_TABLE C;
```